# reloadData every time App is opened and by button

Tags: ios, swift

How can I use this every time my app is opened from background and by button?

**Swift 3**

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please post, what you have tried yet? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Put it in `viewWillAppear()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Catch the foreground notification:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "willEnterForeground:", name: UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
    }

    func willEnterForeground(notification: NSNotification!) {
        // do whatever you want when the app is brought back to the foreground
        self.tableView.reloadData() 
    }

    deinit {
        // make sure to remove the observer when this view controller is dismissed/deallocated

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: nil, object: nil)
    }
}
```

Reload your tableview:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableview.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: You can test. Maybe it's compatible :) (swift 2.2)